# Displaying Date Time in rails 3.2 as in the database without conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Is there any method to display the date time on rails 3 as it is in database?

`:created_at` is stored as

> "2014-11-25 10:55:56.445949"

in database. I need same format everywhere in my rails app. I have used `created_at_before_type_cast` in views, it worked but failed for json response. Can I use default scope? if yes how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strftime` to specify how to display the date, and then on your model define a new property that will return your chosen format:

```
def created_at_formatted
  self.created_at.strftime("%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S.%L")
end
```

Take a look at [this link](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) which describes all of the various representations.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use Active Model Serialization gem, it will give you a power over generating json as you want! Its very powerful and people are using that now.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

In your serializer file:

you can define data of your own. Say you have a Post model and you wanted to generate json response model for it. You may do the following:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :date_for_json

  # look up :subject on the model, but use +title+ in the JSON
  attribute :subject, :key => :title
  has_many :comments
  def date_for_json
      object.created_at.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y") #=> "Printed on 11/19/2007"
  end
end
```

now in your controller when you declare:

```
render json: @products
```

This will give you the output like this:

```
[{id: 1, date_for_json: "Printed on 11/19/2007", id: 2, date_for_json: "Printed on 11/19/2007"}, ....]
```

Well, I just shared the best practice I used to approach for myself. This will give you some good idea to design your api.

Comment: any reason for this downvote? So I can consider them and fix my answer or remove it!

Comment: oh someone downvoted :( I just tried to share what I think best practice is :(